# Check if intel processor supports GVT -g

Tags: graphics, virtualization, gpu

I am trying to do a full graphics virtualisation. I have a intel i7 CPU 920 . In the intel spces sheet it says yes for Intel Virtualization Technology (VT-x). But I am not able to confirm if the processor supports 'full Graphics Virtualisation technology' or GVT -g for short.

Similarly I am not able to confirm if it supports GVT -s or GVT -d.
Is there a way to know what it supports?
I am running Ubuntu 14.04

Answer (score 2):

No. GVT is only supported in Intel CPUs >=4th generation (ex: i5-4200u).

[Source](https://01.org/igvt-g), and [Source2](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X86_virtualization#Graphics_Virtualization_Technology_.28Intel_GVT-d.2C_GVT-g_and_GVT-s.29)

If you have another graphics card (nVidia/AMD) you can use their virtualization technologies.

Comment: Looks like it only says 'KVMGT deliver excellent virtual GPU performance in VMs across 5th and 6th gen and xeon E3 v4 family'.

Comment: Also, I have only one graphics card -> nVidia and no intel or amd graphics card. How can I go about doing a full gpu virtualisation with it as you have mentioned in your answer. Please point to references.

Comment: @PrakharAgrawal GVT was released with [Intel Iris Pro GPUs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X86_virtualization#Graphics_Virtualization_Technology_.28Intel_GVT-d.2C_GVT-g_and_GVT-s.29). That definitely doesn't include your 1st-generation i7 integrated GPU. Now, regarding nVidia's passthrough, you can check out [this article](https://bufferoverflow.io/gpu-passthrough/). Other than that I can't tell you much else. If my answer was correct, please mark it as correct.

Answer (score 1):

Intel GVT-g is only supported by 4th generation processors on XENGT. For KVMGT, only 5th generation processors.

Also to note that 4th generation processors are not actively supported by the developers. If they stop working due to a regression, support will not be reinstated.

Refer to the following mail trail: https://lists.01.org/pipermail/igvt-g/2016-November/001024.html

Comment: A method to check your claim would help the posts, as I believe this is what the posts requires.