# How to check if your Intel CPU supports Intel GVT-g?

Tags: virtualization, cpu, gpu

Is there a tool to check if my current CPU supports Intel GVT-g and are there any special hardware requirements in the BIOS for example that will enable it.

I'm querying specifically for:

- Intel i7-8559U
- Intel i7-6700HQ

And I have a laptop also with paired i7-6700HQ and Intel Graphics HD 630, so this is 6th Generation Laptop so it means [based on this article](https://01.org/igvt-g) that my laptop is GVT-g support, is that correct?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Check if intel processor supports GVT -g](https://askubuntu.com/questions/858040/check-if-intel-processor-supports-gvt-g)

Comment: My question is a bit more specific than that one, I saw that post also. Thanks for noting @singrium